# Infinite loop using Spring Security - Login page is protected even though it should allow anonymous access

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I have a Spring application (Spring version **2.5.6.SEC01**, Spring Security version **2.0.5**) with the following setup:

**web.xml**

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>
    index.jsp
  </welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The **index.jsp** page is in the WebContent directory and simply contains a redirect:

```
<c:redirect url="/login.htm"/>
```

In the **appname-servlet.xml**, there is a view resolver to point to the jsp pages in WEB-INF/jsp

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

In the **security-config.xml** file, I have the following configuration:

```
<http>
  <!-- Restrict URLs based on role -->
  <intercept-url pattern="/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/logoutSuccess*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />

  <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" filters="none" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />

  <form-login login-page="/login.jsp"/>
</http>

<authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
</authentication-provider>
```

However, I can't even navigate to the login page and get the following error in the log:

> WARNING: The login page is being
>   protected by the filter chain, but you
>   don't appear to have anonymous
>   authentication enabled. This is almost
>   certainly an error.

I've tried changing the ROLE_ANONYMOUS to IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, changing the login-page to index.jsp, login.htm, and adding different intercept-url values, but I can't get it so the login page is accesible and security applies to the other pages.  What do I have to change to avoid this loop?

Comment: Put loggin level to DEBUG and post it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was I was missing the

```
<anonymous />
```

tag in the http section of the **security-config.xml** file so I wasn't able to get to the login page anonymously.  Once I added this, I was able to get to the login page and authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `auto-config` attribute:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url ... />
    ...
</http>
```

**EDIT:**
To avoid problems with multiple UserDetailsService you probably can replace your `<authentication-provider>` declaration by something like this:

```
<authentication-provider user-service-ref = "userService" />

<jdbc-user-service id = "userService" data-source-ref="dataSource" />
```

Comment: If I set auto-config to true, I get the following error: "More than one UserDetailsService registered. Please use a specific Id in your configuration"

If I remove the authentication-provider from the security xml, this error goes away, but when I try to navigate to the login page, I have to do http authentication instead of the form authentication I want.

Comment: Just so people don't wonder, the `auto-config` attribute is basically just adding `<anonymous/>` to the configuration (and a couple other unnecessary things).

Answer (score 0):

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
```

you could have replaced that with

```
<intercept-url pattern="/login*" filter="none" />
```

because spring security is right, it doesn't make any sense to protect the login page

Answer (score 0):

you can use another sec:http section

```
<sec:http pattern="/login" security="none" />
```

or you can use

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```